# File execution is denied

Tags: linux, filesystems, access-control

I just can't execute any file.

For example:[image: example]

And I use `zsh` now,`bash` has the same problem.

Comment: The ACL seems to be correct,  maybe the script is located in a filesystem mounted with the noexec options (This option overrides POSIX permissions to prevent any file on that filesystem from being executed). ?

Comment: Whether that filesystem is mounted `noexec` might be good to know, and also what the precise contents of the first line of that file is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [Edouard Fazenda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/90678/edouard-fazenda) and [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig).
I have solved this problem with their help.

I mounted my `/home` with fourth field `rw,relation,user`.

After read some doc,I use fourth field `rw,relation,exec,suid`.
Now everything goes fine!Thanks again.